# RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob data format

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi

We are exporting a public and private key.  The private key is to be consumed by non .net software written in Magic.  The developers have questions around the format of the exported key.  Is there a whitepaper or other resource that explains the format of the exported data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very useful documentation on the exported blob types:
[Base Provider Key BLOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There was not much documentation when I looked years ago. You'll find some on MSDN but the most helpful are the C header files for CryptoAPI.

But if you consider code as documentation then I suggest you to read (**disclaimer: mine**) the [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/CryptoConvert.cs) which has to interop with those structures.

You might also want to use the XML format, e.g. `ToXmlString(true);`, which might prove easier to parse/use than the byte buffers.